# Dart convert simple class to extension

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

here i pasted my simple class which i can convert English numbers to Arabic numbers and i would like to convert that to extension

```
class Strings{
  static String replaceFarsiNumber(String input, bool reverse) {
    const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

    /*en to fa*/
    if (reverse) {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(farsi[i], english[i]);
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

as i new in `extensions` in dart and i'm using this class in `flutter` how can i convert it to extension basically:

```
extension ConvertNum on String {
  static const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  static const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

  String changeNUm(String input, bool reverse) {
    /*en to fa*/
    if (reverse) {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(farsi[i], english[i]);
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. Basically, inside and extension, use `this` to refer to the current string:

```
extension ConvertNum on String {
  static const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  static const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

  String changeNUm(bool reverse) {
    /*en to fa*/
    String input = this;
    if (reverse) {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
        input = input.replaceAll(farsi[i], english[i]);
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

Comment: so, how can i pass string to `changeNum` method and specify `reverse` parameter?

Comment: no, you don't pass a string, you invoke the method on a string instead, so like this: `"1234".changeNum(true);`

Comment: thanks a lot, how can i define this extension in another file and use that?

Comment: Super easy. Just put the extension in a separate file and import it when you need it.